# Merging specific columns from multiple excel files with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract the "Rep", "Units" & "Total" columns from these 3 respective excel files into a new excel file

[SampleData](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RbG76av_2kFXsKv_RstsC3PTmSXkcPp9/view?usp=sharing)
[SampleData3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jet3cbsqydsYwktspbIsscFl250BTRQU/view?usp=sharing)
[SampleData4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10xUlClZ2xbfFLrwUl40HAe4ELOvJV2BO/view?usp=sharing)

but the columns are not showing side by side, instead they are showing from the cell of the bottom-right corner of each other.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

path0 = "SampleData.xlsx"
path1 = "SampleData3.xlsx"
path2 = "SampleData4.xlsx"

df0 = pd.read_excel(path0)
df1 = pd.read_excel(path1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(path2)

values0 = df0[['Rep']]
values1 = df1[['Units']]
values2 = df2[['Total']]

dataframes = [values0, values1, values2]
join = pd.concat(dataframes)
join.to_excel("output_final.xlsx")
```

Output
[image: Outputs]
[image: Outputs]

Can anyone please tell me where ami I doing something wrong?
Advance thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your may have to apply axis=1, as below

```
join = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
```

and in case if your column length is uneven then you may also choose to pass ignore_index

```
join = pd.concat(dataframes,ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `axis=1`

```
join = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
```

It will concat along the columns, default is `axis=0` which concatenates along the index i.e. row.

**Sample Input**:

```
>>df1
  units
0    mg
1    gm
2    kg

>>df2
   values
0     230
1      40
2       9
```

**Sample Output**:

```
>>join
  units  values
0    mg     230
1    gm      40
2    kg       9
```